# Is there a way to make a URL clickable in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This wasn't a problem until I took a look at my website in Chrome and noticed the links not clickable like Firefox:

Firefox ( clickable link)

[image: firefox]

Chrome ( unclickable )

[image: chrome]

In my view, I want my `exact_url` field to be clickable. This is how it is right now. I use truncate just encase the link is to big:

```
<%= truncate(up.exact_url, :length => 140) %>
```

Is there way to make the view register that it's a link? If no, then how do I fix this link issue I'm having in Chrome?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding why you want a link in a `text_field` tag to be clickable?  If it's a link, use a link_to tag.  If it's text_field, why are you using it as a linkable object?  Kinda confusing to the user

Comment: @iWasRobbed The text isn't from my website so I don't think it can use link_to, unless I'm wrong? These links are just copy and pasted links from other websites.

Comment: So... you are storing a field called `exact_url` with a link to some external website?  Why are you displaying that link in a `text_field` tag?  Does the user copy/paste them into your text_field, then you save it, then you display it to other users?  Please explain more about what you are doing and what you are *trying* to do.

Comment: @iWasRobbed Your exactly right, you copy paste a URL inside of the `exact_url` text_field when you create it. Sorry I got my fields mixed up, in the view its not a text_field at all. What I meant was what you said. I will edit my question. What I am really asking about is the view and how to make it clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be specifying them as links if you want them to be clickable links:

```
<%= link_to(truncate(up.exact_url, :length => 140), up.exact_url) %>
```

That way you truncate the link text to 140 chars and leave the actual URL intact when they click on it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaking what you really mean, can't you just use:

```
<%= link_to truncate(up.exact_url, :length => 140), up.exact_url  %>
```

Normally, you can't just put the url of a link into the text of a webpage and expect it to just magically become clickable. It looks like some browsers do naturally do this... but it's definitely the exception.

So - to turn them into links, you actually have to *make* them links with `link_to`. This will insert the proper `a href=` tag to make it a link that will be recognised by all browsers.

Comment: I'm getting a `SyntaxError` after `link_to`.

Comment: Indeed, FF is just interpreting the text as a link and making it clickable. This is the magic formula which seems to be missing.

Comment: Tried: `<%= link_to truncate(up.exact_url, :length => 140) %>` ?

Comment: ah yep - wasn't sure if rails did that, thus was being certain. Of course it makes sense - and it works too.

Comment: You actually don't want to do it this way since you're truncating the link's href contents.  You want to truncate the link text while leaving the href intact.